# The method getLong(String, long) in the type SharedPreferences is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: java, android, string, sharedpreferences, long-integer

I'm getting an error message stating "The method getLong(String, long) in the type SharedPreferences is not applicable for the arguments (String)" on the line (all the way at the end of my code):

```
 long oldTime = pref.getLong("smstimestamp");
```

However I'm not sure how this can be resolved.

Any suggestions?

SOURCE:

```
public class DataCountService extends Service {
    String text = "USR;1";
    String ERROR = "DataCountService";
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private final long PERIOD = 1000 * 15; // x min
    private final long DELAY_INTERVAL = 0; // x Seconds

    private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Logging Service Started");

        if (intent == null) {
            // Exit gracefully is service not started by intent
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: Null Intent");
        } else {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            text = extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT);
            // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
            if (text.contains("//USR;1")) {

                // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                totalBytes /= 1000000;
                mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                String tag = ";";
                String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                String info = String.format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag, mobileStr,
                        totalStr);

                // check to ensure proper time has elapsed
                // long days_30 = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
                SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences("DataCountService", 0);
                // long oldTime = pref.getLong("smstimestamp");
                // if(System.currentTimeMillis() - oldTime > days_30){

                // send traffic info via sms & save the current time
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
                            Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    String shortCode = settings.getString(
                            Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                            Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, info, null,
                            null);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putLong("smstimestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
                    editor.commit();

                } else {
                    SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE,
                            null, info, null, null);
                }

                String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
            } else if

            (text.contains("//USR;0")) {
                stopSelf();

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to any other
                // character
            } else {

                Log.e(ERROR, "Invalid Enable/Disable Value");

            }
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    // }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        startServiceTimer();
    }

    /*
     * @Override public void onCreate() extends PhoneStateListener {
     * 
     * 
     * EndCallListener callListener = new EndCallListener(); TelephonyManager
     * mTM = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     * mTM.listen(callListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE); }
     */

    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // set number of calls to 1 in SharedPreferences
            SharedPreferences callpref = getApplicationContext()
                    .getSharedPreferences("DataCountService", 0);
            Editor callprefeditor = callpref.edit();
            callprefeditor.putString("calls", "1");
            callprefeditor.commit();


        }

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                "DataCountService", 0);

        if (pref.getString("calls", "1") == "1") {

            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
            if (text.contains("USI;1;")) {




        //      String swappedMdn(Context ctx){ 
                    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    //Extract the phone number from the TelephonyManager instance
                    String mdn = tm.getLine1Number();
                    //Insure MDN is 10 characters
                    if (mdn.length() < 10 || mdn == null) mdn ="0000000000";
                    //Extract last 10 digits of MDN
                    if (mdn.length() > 10) mdn = mdn.substring(mdn.length() - 10, mdn.length()); 
                    char data[] = mdn.toCharArray();
                    char digit;
                    for (int index = 0; index < mdn.length() - (mdn.length())%2; index+=2){
                        digit = data[index];
                        data[index] = data[index+1];
                        data[index+1] = digit;
                    }
                    return; 
                }



                // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                totalBytes /= 1000000;
                mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                String tag = ";";
                String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                String info = String.format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag, mobileStr,
                        totalStr);

                // check to ensure proper time has elapsed
                 long days_30 = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
                 long oldTime = pref.getLong("smstimestamp");
                 if(System.currentTimeMillis() - oldTime > days_30){

                // send traffic info via sms & save the current time
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager
                        .sendTextMessage("7865555555", null, info, null, null);
                String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putLong("smstimestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
                editor.commit();
```

Comment: See the Java API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getLong(java.lang.String, long) It should accept **Two** parameters. **EXACTLY** as the compiler is telling you. Pass **0** as the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't find the key `"smstimestamp"` it returns a default value, in this case `0`.

```
long oldTime = pref.getLong("smstimestamp", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

What is there to fix? The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) clearly states that you need two attributes:

```
abstract long getLong(String key, long defValue)
```

So, call `getLong()` with a certain *default* attribute (depends what you expect when there is no value in *prefs*. Maybe just `0` or `-1`).

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to access a value in shared preferences, it expects a default value (if the key is not found). So change it as :

```
long oldTime = pref.getLong("smstimestamp", 0);
```

where 0 is the default value you want.

> defValue :    Value to return if this preference does not exist

Answer (score 0):

The class SharedPreferences has a method getLong(String, long) with two parameters. Yo can´t call it only with one parameter.

The second parmeter (the long), probably is the default value to return if there is no a "preference" with the key "smstimestamp". Put any value (0 or -1) and verify the returned value

```
long oldTime = pref.getLong("smstimestamp"-1);
if (oldTime==-1) {
   // There is no smstimestamp
}
```